# Javascript, onclick, Uncaught ReferenceError: FAVOURITES is not defined

Tags: javascript, onclick, referenceerror

I have an `Uncaught ReferenceError: FAVOURITES is not defined(onclick)`, i don't understand where is my sintax error in `button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table(" + table +")");`.

```js
ContactLoader.table =
 function(table){
  ContactLoader.CURRENT_PATTERN = null;
  ContactLoader.CURRENT_TABLE = table;
  ContactLoader.CURRENT_LETTER = "A";
  ContactLoader.loadData();
 }

function generateSearchLetter(){
 
 var divSearch = document.getElementById("search");
 if(divSearch.lastChild.id === "search_name");
  divSearch.removeChild(divSearch.lastChild);
 
 var divSearchLetter = document.createElement('div');
 divSearchLetter.setAttribute("id", "search_letter");
 divSearch.appendChild(divSearchLetter);
 
 
 var divAllFav = document.createElement('div');
 divAllFav.setAttribute("class", "search_all_favourites");
 divSearchLetter.appendChild(divAllFav);
 
 var arr1 = new Array("ALL","FAVOURITES");
 
 for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
  
        var button  = document.createElement('div');
  
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(arr1[i]);
  button.appendChild(textNode);
  var table = button.textContent;
  
  button.setAttribute("class" , "letterAF");
  button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table(" + table +")"); 
  
  
  divAllFav.appendChild(button); 
 }
}
```

Comment: It should most likely be `button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table('" + table +"')");` instead of just `button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table(" + table +")");`.

Comment: `button.setAttribute("onclick", ...);` is *not* a good way to setup JavaScript events.  May I suggest `button.addEventListener('click', function(){});`?

Comment: With  button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table(' " + table +" ')");  pass 'FAVOURITES' like a string.

Comment: With addEventListener have problem with argument to pass. I thank you however

Answer (score 1):

As you're trying to bind an `event` to a `DOM element`, ***it's not*** a good idea to bind click event using `setAttribute`. This approach is been deprecated since many years ago.
To `bind` the `click` event to the `button` variable, it is better to replace:

```
button.setAttribute("onclick", "ContactLoader.table(" + table +")");
```

with

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
   ContactLoader.table(table);
});
```

Comment: Ok. thank you for this explanation, but doing copy and paste of this code, the event doesn't add to button.